# Send html form to variable php

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I have a html form, and i want that when u send the value of the html, to be a php variable

```
<form action="callback2.php" method="POST">
Telefoon nummer invoeren: <input type="text" size="10" name="nummerb" id="nummerb"> <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

this is the html and the value of this should be

```
$nummerb ="" ;
```

so the nummerb should have the value of the sended form.

Comment: What are your efforts on this?

Comment: Believe me, you do ***not*** want this. Not automagically at least. This is good old register_globals.

Comment: Please take the time to type "you" instead of "u". Please take the time to read the manual or one of the nearly infinite tutorials or examples on HTML forms in PHP. Please stop giving reasons to pollute StackOverflow with "What have you tried?". What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in a comment:

> i know that it should be $nummerb = $_POST ['nummerb']; but when i put
>   that in an run it, it says Undefined index, so it means it can't find
>   the 'nummerb'. So i should put ifisset right?

So the answer is:

```
$nummerb = "";
if(isset($_POST['nummerb']))    
  $nummerb = $_POST['nummerb'] ;
```

You also can check first if you got a form submission to make sure you do not check for the **$nummerb** if the user didn't pressed on the *Send* button:

- add a name to your submit button

`<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="submit"/>`

- check if the user clicked on the submit button:

```
<?php

// If the user pressed on submit button
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {

  // Get the nummerb
  $nummerb = "";
  if(isset($_POST['nummerb']))    
    $nummerb = $_POST['nummerb'] ;

  // Do your job here
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this very basic and silly question is:

```
$nummerb = $_POST["nummerb"];
```

You should learn more PHP before asking another question here.

The answer to your question could have been found within the PHP manual.

A simple Google query for `php post` returns the answers you are looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: i know that it should be $nummerb = $_POST ['nummerb'];

but when i put that in an run it, it says Undefined index, so it means it can't find the 'nummerb'. So i should put ifisset right?

Comment: Indeed. You have to check that it is in the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for what you are looking.
But your html should be:

```
<form action="callback2.php" method="POST">
Telefoon nummer invoeren:
<input type="text" size="10" name="nummerb" id="nummerb">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And php code should be like that:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $nummerb = $_POST['nummerb'] ;
  }
```

Comment: i know that it should be $nummerb = $_POST ['nummerb']; but when i put that in an run it, it says Undefined index, so it means it can't find the 'nummerb'. So i should put ifisset right?

Comment: right...I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access nummerb by this :

```
$nummerb = $_POST['nummerb'] ;
```

Or if you don't want to create "manually" the variables, use [extract](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.extract.php) function :

```
extract($_POST);
echo $nummerb;
```

Comment: i know that it should be $nummerb = $_POST ['nummerb'];

but when i put that in an run it, it says Undefined index, so it means it can't find the 'nummerb'. So i should put ifisset right?